# Matrix multiplied by a vector without using numpy

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Without using numpy in python

I am running into the error "object of type 'int' has no len()" when running the code below when multiplying the matrix C with the vector A.

Any help would be appreciated

```
A = [3, 4, 8]
C = [[2, 9, 7], [3, 4, 1], [1, 6, 5]]

def MM(C, A):
  c = []
  for i in range(0, len(C)):
    temp=[]
    for j in range(0, len(A[0])):
        s = 0
        for k in range(0, len(C[0])):
            s += C[i][k] * A[k][j]
        temp.append(s)
    c.append(temp)
  return c
print("Matrix C multiplied by vector A is: \n", MM(C, A))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for j in range(0, len(A[0])):
```

`A[0]` is 3, which is an integer and has no attribute `len`. `A` is also a 1D array so `A[k][j]` will also raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't stepped through your entire logic to fix the code, but I see the error.

In this line you try to take the length of A[0] `for j in range(0, len(A[0]))`

You have defined A as:
`A = [3,4,8]`

Therefore `A[0] = 3` and is an integer, which doesn't have a `len()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `A = [[3], [4], [8]]`. When the matrix is on the left side of the multiplication, you are multiplying it with a column vector instead of a row vector.

Keeping your code the same, but changing A as mentioned, I get the output:

```
[[98], [33], [67]]
```

which corresponds to the 3x1 column vector you would expect to get by doing this matrix multiplication.

If you instead wanted A to be a row vector on the left side of the multiplication, you could set:

```
A = [[3, 4, 8]]
C = [[2, 9, 7], [3, 4, 1], [1, 6, 5]]
```

and print

```
print("The vector A multiplied by the matrix C is: \n", MM(A, C))
```

to give the output:

```
[[26, 91, 65]]
```

This would be a 1x3 row vector multiplied by a 3x3 matrix to give a 1x3 result.